# Using XSLT with one type of variable

Tags: xslt, variables

Is there a way to use just one way of using a variable within XSLT?

For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="myvar" select="title" />
```

Which selects the title from my xml, then I would like to use it within the template:

```
<h2 title="{$myvar}">{$myvar}</h2>
```

However it only shows the title attribute.
And when I do it like this:

```
<h2 title="<xsl:value-of select='$myvar'>"><xsl:value-of select='$myvar'></h2>
```

It only works the other way around.

So my question:

**Is there one way that works for both attribute and content?**

Comment: Why can't you use just `<h2 title="{$myvar}"><xsl:value-of select='$myvar'></h2>`?

Comment: @Alberteddu the single quotes around $myvar will select that as a string.

Comment: My copy & paste was careless. :-D Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can avoid AVT:

```
<h2>
 <xsl:attribute name="title">
  <xsl:value-of select=$myvar/>
 </xsl:attribute>
 <xsl:value-of select=$myvar/>
</h2>
```

But I think it's simpler using AVT and `xsl:value-of` properly:

```
<h2 title="{$myvar}">
 <xsl:value-of select=$myvar/>
</h2>
```

Comment: well the idea was that I could allow an end user to just add some simple tags which I can then replace by the same string. But since this isn't possible I've just used a regular expression now to identify the ones in an attribute, then replace those with the curly brackets version, and leaving the rest in the nodes replacing them with the value-of version.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT uses XML syntax, which is why you can't have an xsl:value-of instruction inside an attribute: hence the AVT notation using curly braces. It would be nice if the language allowed curly braces inside text nodes as well, but it doesn't.